# Selenium script fails - session deleted because of page crash/invalid session ID

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web-scraper using Selenium on Ubuntu 18.04 (EC2 instance) that keeps failing. It will work sporadically (i.e. runs completely), but sooner or later always crashes.

```
print ('start script!')  
import regex
import time
import requests
import string
import json
import geocoder
from datetime import datetime
import mapbox
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt 
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

import os
import sys
import subprocess



today_date = dt.today()
newdate = today_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1) #for testing, we'll put 1
today = today_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
three_days_away = newdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Set base url
base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/c/madison-wi?date='+today+'T00%3A00%3A00%2C'+three_days_away+'T23%3A00%3A00&date_filter=Choose+Dates&calendarTrigger=false'

driver.get(base_url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    expandAll = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='View All']")))
    expandAll.click()
    print("View All Clicked")
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
    pass


def scroll_down():
    """A method for scrolling the page."""

    # Get scroll height.
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:

        # Scroll down to the bottom.
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load the page.
        time.sleep(2)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height.
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:

            break

        last_height = new_height

scroll_down()



events = []


find_href = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e')
for my_href in find_href:
    time.sleep(4)
    link = my_href.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)
    events.append(link)

print("events list is", events)
print("total events: ", (len(events)))


# GET request user-agent
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}

# iterate through all events and open them.
item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        driver.get(event)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

It is failing here:

```
driver.get(event)
```

With an error message like this:

```
Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=101.0.4951.41)

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id

Message: invalid session id
```

What I've tried:

I've increased the size of my EC2 instance and running on 16gb instance now (r6i.large).  I have 13gb available, so it really shouldn't be a memory issue.

What else can I try?  The script runs fine locally, so it's something when running this on Ubuntu using EC2.

Comment: how did you solve this in the end? I'm experiencing the same issue , also only when running on a VM...

Comment: Hi there, you know I'm not sure I ever really resolved this.  Selenium was always buggy and very hard to work with for me personally and I set this project aside for the time being.  I would suggest updated selenium/chromedriver/chrome and making sure your instance has enough memory. .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I also haven't figured it out (everything is up to date) ....

Answer (score 0):

If the browser session has crashed, you can't just put `continue` in `except:` and think the next `.get()` would work. It's *crashed*.

Re-create `driver` in `except:` as you did at the top of the script, or put it in a function.

```py
def get_driver():
    # you can put chrome options here too
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)  # do it just once here
    return driver

...

try:
   driver.get(event)
except:  # try to catch a specific error
   print(e)
   driver = get_driver()
   continue
```

Comment: I tried this. I goes through like one url and then crashes with the same error, Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=101.0.4951.41)

Comment: I'm really trying to figure out why it's crashing.

Comment: I almost wonder if it has something to do with the website detecting my scraper.  I see no other reason this should be crashing.

Comment: If you don't get the error while running the same script locally, then I don't think it's the website detecting your scraper. It could be the scraper running too fast on AWS and DDoSing the website 